# Passing parameter to asmx web-service in Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, postman

I have created a asmx web-service like below:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetEmployeesJSONByID(int sId)
{
  try {
    string sResult = string.Empty;
    List<Employee> lstEmp = new List<Employee>();

    List<Employee> lstEmpNew = new List<Employee>();

    lstEmp.Add(new Employee { Id = 101, Name = "Nitin", Salary = 10000 });
    lstEmp.Add(new Employee { Id = 102, Name = "Dinesh", Salary = 20000 });

    switch (sId) {
      case 101: 
        lstEmpNew.Add(new Employee { Id = 101, Name = "Nitin", Salary = 10000 });
         break;
       case 102:
         lstEmpNew.Add(new Employee { Id = 102, Name = "Dinesh", Salary = 20000 });
         break;
       default:
         break;
     }
     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     sResult = js.Serialize(lstEmpNew);

     Context.Response.Write(sResult);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     Context.Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
   }
 }
```

I want to test this web-service via Postman. So I deployed in my local IIS and in the postman like below:

[image]

In the URL I given as

```
http://XXXXXX/SampleWebService/Service.asmx/GetEmployeesJSONByID?sId=101
```

I am getting the Request Format is invalid. How to pass this sId in the postman to test this webservice?

Comment: Is `webservices` defined in web.config to use HttpGet?

Comment: Yes, we have defined that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the `<system.web>` block in Web.config file:

```
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Well the error image in the question has the request method as POST in Postman and the Source code has UseHttpGet = true for the WebMethod.

Comment: these protocols i already added in the config file. Actually it is Get Method, so i changed the POST to GET in postman and it worked as expected. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: use the below link for the reference 
  https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests